# ¿Por qué me dá error al intentar reproducir un sonido en Python con PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy practicando un poco con la librería PyGame, pero tengo un problema, cuando intento hacer que se reproduzca un sonido, al ejecutar el programa me devuelve el siguiente error

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luciano/via_25/via25.py", line 11, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory
```

Parte del código es este:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
# cargar música
pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/background001.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
músicaSonando = True
#---------------------------------
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.key == ord('m'):
            if músicaSonando:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
        músicaSonando = not músicaSonando
```

He buscado información en internet y no he encontrado mucho, pero creo que quizá puede ser un problema de drivers y no de código.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ha probado con un punto delante? "./home/lu en fin el problema es de la ruta

Comment: No es problema de la ruta del archivo a reproducir realmente, el problema es con ALSA que no encuentra dispositivo de salida para reproducir, el error viene heredado del intento de conexión con PulseAudio  en SDL, ¿Qué te muestra `pacmd list-sources`
 en una terminal?